# GridView - Index was out of range

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got error like:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection. Parameter name: index

my code is,

```
int index = 0;
        GridViewRow gvrow;
        GridViewRow previousRow;
        if (e.CommandName == "Up")
        {
            index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            gvrow = GridView2.Rows[index];
            previousRow = GridView2.Rows[index - 1];
            int mobilePriority = Convert.ToInt32(GridView2.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
            int mobileId = Convert.ToInt32(gvrow.Cells[0].Text);
            int previousId = Convert.ToInt32(previousRow.Cells[0].Text);
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("update AppointmentMaster set Priority='" + (mobilePriority - 1) + "' where AppointmentId='" + mobileId + "'; update AppointmentMaster set Priority='" + (mobilePriority) + "' where AppointmentId='" + previousId + "'", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: What  have you trued to fix this?

Comment: what s wrong with this line...   "int mobilePriority = Convert.ToInt32(GridView2.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString());"

Comment: Try Console.WriteLinining `GridView2.DataKeys.Count()`. The result will be clear.

Comment: 3 years and 7 months and STILL can't ask a proper question?? This has been solved here WAY TOO MANY TIMES already. Do some research on your part, don't expect everything on a silver plate.

Comment: @walther i agree. this is such a basic problem. with a lot of the questions I see here, it's like the poster didn't even put one ounce of effort forward.

Answer (score 1):

```
previousRow = GridView2.Rows[index - 1];
```

(index - 1) will be -1, since index == 0.

Comment: I see you're new here, but please, don't encourage laziness here. Thank you.